# Is it possible to add a button to an existing panel or node with python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to add a new button to an existing panel or an existing node that runs a custom operator?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. You need to find the class that defines that panel (usually pretty easy to do by right-clicking a button or setting in the panel and choosing *Edit Source*). From there, you just need to define a function and append it to that class. As an example, I do this in my [Render Music](https://github.com/Fweeb/blender_render_music) add-on (in `__init__.py`, starting at line 82). Below is the relevant example that adds two checkboxes (properties defined by the add-on) to the Render Panel (`RENDER_PT_render`):

```
def render_panel(self, context):
    user_prefs = context.user_preferences
    addon_prefs = user_prefs.addons[__package__].preferences

    layout = self.layout
    layout.prop(addon_prefs, "use_play")
    layout.prop(addon_prefs, "use_end")


# Registration

def register():
    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.append(render_panel)

# Unregistration

def unregister():
    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.remove(render_panel)
```

Comment: You explain how to add a panel to another, but not how to remove in the unregister method. I believe it is by using `remove` instead of `append`.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I left it off in the reply because I didn't want to confuse the issue too much. The unregister function is in the full source that's linked, though.

Comment: Note: *Edit Source* is available by enabling "Developer Extras" in the preferences menu (Preferences > Interface ).